# Laravel 'required' rule not working on Request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5

I have a Request that I've built but the `required` rule is not working correctly.

Route

```
Route::get('v1/learning_centre/user/{userId}/course/list', 'API\LearningCentre@userCourses');
```

Controller

```
public function userCourses(GetUserCourses $request)
{
    $courses = User::findOrFail($request->userId)
                    ->courses()
                    ->get();

    return new CourseResourceCollection($courses);
}
```

Request

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\LearningCentre;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class GetUserCourses extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'userId' => 'required|integer'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'userId.required' => 'A User is required',
        ];
    } }
```

If I turn off the `required` rule I can get to the controller. If I have the `required` rule in the request I get a 302.  I am passing in a valid userId in phpunit.  Without the request rules my code works as intended.

Any ideas?

Comment: have u added `{{ csrf_field() }}` to form ?

Comment: It's a get request, should I need to add that? I'm also using phpunit to test it so theres no front end.  Also as I said if I remove the required rule it all works perfectly.  It's as if the `GetUserCourses` cannot see the variable.

Comment: Why are you using a FormRequest at all on a `GET`?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because I'm building an API and I want to give meaningful responses if someone incorrectly passes a variable and building that into the Request seems like a good way to go.  Also I'm using a library which will build my documentation for me if I do it this way.

Comment: It's entirely possible to do those things without abusing the FormRequest class.

Comment: Yea it is but if I use this library https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator It all gets done for me. But yea I think you are right that its abusing the form request a little. Frustrating because the library won't automatically build the rules.

Comment: @hdifen I don't have personal experience with that library, but Marcel is awesome and I strongly suspect it can handle route-model-bindings correctly. I do see folks in the issues list asking how to do it and getting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) to validate a required GET parameter in this situation, not a FormRequest class, which, as the name should indicate, are intended for *form requests*.

Your route:

```
Route::get('v1/learning_centre/user/{user}/course/list', 'API\LearningCentre@userCourses');
```

Your controller:

```
public function userCourses(User $user) {
```

If a user ID is missing (or an invalid one used), your controller will automatically throw a `ModelNotFoundException`, which Laravel by default returns as a 404.

Comment: Yes this is correct. My assumption is is that the 'required' rule looks for data in the input and not in the url even though you can access the variable the same way when using $request.  Since I'm using it as it's not intended this "bug" happens.